# Is there a way to "deallocate" id's that were allocated?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say I have allocated a block of IDs using the `allocateIdRange` method. Is there a way to undo this? I'm nervous about allocating large chunks of IDs without having a way to undo it and potentially/accidentally allocating a large range of IDs that will never be able to be allocated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No, it is not possible to `deallocate` Ids after using `allocateIdRange` method.

**Long Answer:** After a lot of testing with this method, I think it is not possible to "deallocate" those IDs. Even looking at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#method-summary) for Datastore or the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary) for the App Engine API for any possible methods.

Since you're concerned about allocating a lot and then not able to allocate again them because those are already reserved, I'll just say that being careful is the best option since there is no built-in method in the libs to `deallocate`.

Comment: Thanks for looking. This is what I was afraid of...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this personally, but I would just think you could do a delete on the keys to wanted to 'deallocate'. Just as if you were deleting an entity in general.

Comment: Since `allocateIdRange` and `allocateIds` don't create entities, just allocate the IDs for manual entry, not sure you can delete it(?) Maybe I'm wrong?